# column to row conversion with ranges in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a table detailing Project Schedules.

```
ProjectID | StartMonth | EndMonth
---------------------------------
1           2            5
2           3            8
3           6            10
```

I want run a query to generate one row for each month in each project. For example, ProjectID = 1, requires rows for months 2 through 5.

```
ProjectID | Month
-----------------
1           2
1           3
1           4
1           5
2           3
2           4
2           5
2           6
2           7
2           8
3           6
3           7
3           8
3           9
3           10
```

I'm using Access, but for the benefit of StackOverflow community, I'd like to build a solution that is platform agnostic.

The only technique that comes to mind is double `for` loop that unions rows together with each iteration in the inner most loop.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE / CLARIFICATION**

StartMonth and EndMonth are integer values relative to a Julian date. So for example, an entry could be:

```
ProjectID | StartMonth | EndMonth
---------------------------------
10          2            236
```

This means the system has been monitoring the project from the 2nd through the 236th month from starting. It only records events that occurred between the 2nd thru the 236th month.

Though for many months no events occur and nothing get occurred. The PM wants to have table that has rows for all months and have zeros for months where no activity was recorded in the system.

Answer (score 4):

Create a table called Months with the numbers 1-12 in a Month field. Then this is your query

```
SELECT  p.ProjectID
       ,m.Month
FROM   Months m
       INNER JOIN
       Projects p ON p.StartMonth<=m.Month AND p.EndMonth>=m.Month
```

This technique is so useful and comes up so often that I have a table called IndexTable with intigers from 0 to 1,000,000.

By the way - it seems unusual to me that the you would not have any projects that span more than one year.

Comment: They do span more then one year. StartMonth reference to the month the project was "commissioned". So for ProjectID=1, the system has data about the project from the 2nd through the 5th month of operation.

Comment: EndMonth could be any integer number of months not just 1-12. Is there any way to dynamic build the list rather then having a large integer table of 1-1,000,000.

Comment: **For conversation consistency, I have updated my original post to clarify the StartMonth and EndMonth definitions.**

Comment: You could dynamically create it ... But don't. 1,000,000 integers take up 4MB of disk space which costs next to nothing. RDMS are really really good at looking things up and building selection sets but are really really bad at things that C# and VB are good at like a 1,000,000 iterations of a loop.